# How to add a checkbox to TSaveDialog in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tcheckbox, tsavedialog

I want to add a checkbox or other VCL component to the TSaveDialog.

Cantu says,

> The new Vista Open and Save dialog boxes (implemented by the IFileOpenDialog and
>        IFileSaveDialog  interfaces) are directly mapped by the new FileOpenDialog and
>        FileSaveDialog components, but also the standard OpenDialog and SaveDialog component uses
>        the new style when the global UseLatestCommonDialogs is set.

I have no idea what that means (I've never done any Interface programming...)

And I don't want to use third party tools.

I saw it suggested on a web search just now that I look at the TOpenPictureDialog code and copy it.

Before trying any of the paths, I thought I'd ask here for some guidance. Any suggestions on an XP through Win7 solution to adding a checkbox to a modern File, Open dialog box in a Windows-version independent manner?

Tom

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Robert, you can do that using a dialog template.

First you must store the template as a resource in your app, then load the template using the [`TOpenFilename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (don't worry by the name, is the same for open and save dialogs) and finally call the [`GetSaveFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function passing the `TOpenFilename` structure.

check this sample

Create a resource file (calledSaveDialog.rc) with the dialog template (look the MyCheckBox added)

```
MYSAVEFILE DIALOG -1, 1, 300, 60
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
CAPTION ""
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
CONTROL "MyCheckBox", 666, "button", BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 84, 19, 60, 12
}
```

this is the source code

```
Uses
 CommDlg;

var
  lpofn    : TOpenFilename;
  lpstrFile: Array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;

{$R *.dfm}
{$R SaveDialog.Res}

function _lpfnHook(hdlg: HWND; uiMsg:UINT;wParam:WPARAM;lParam:LPARAM): UINT stdcall;
begin
  Result:=0;
  case uiMsg of
    // Set the initial state of mycheckbox to checked
    WM_INITDIALOG : CheckDlgButton(hdlg,666,BST_CHECKED);
    WM_COMMAND    :
                   case wParam of
                    666:
                         begin
                          if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hdlg,666)=BST_CHECKED) then
                           ShowMessage('MyCheckBox was checked')
                          else
                          if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hdlg,666)=BST_UNCHECKED) then
                            ShowMessage('MyCheckBox was unchecked');
                         end;
                   end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lpofn,sizeof(lpofn));
  lpofn.lStructSize       := SizeOf(lpofn);
  lpofn.hwndOwner         := Handle;
  lpofn.hInstance         := hInstance;
  //set the filter name
  lpofn.lpstrFilter       := 'All files (*.*)'#0'*.*'#0#0;
  lpofn.lpstrTitle        := 'Save As';
  lpofn.lpstrFile         := lpstrFile;
  lpofn.nMaxFile          := MAX_PATH;
  //Set the template Name
  lpofn.lpTemplateName    :='MYSAVEFILE';
  //set the callback function
  lpofn.lpfnHook          := _lpfnHook;
  lpofn.Flags             := OFN_EXPLORER or OFN_CREATEPROMPT or  OFN_HIDEREADONLY or
                             OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST or OFN_ENABLEHOOK or OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE;
  //execute the dialog
  if GetSaveFileName(lpofn) then ShowMessage(lpofn.lpstrFile);
end;
```

and this is the output

[image]

Comment: Nicely done, RRUZ.  Great answer, plus sample code, and shows screen capture of the result.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with a template but this leads to the legacy dialogs in Vista/7. On those platforms you should make use of [IFileDialogCustomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775912(v=vs.85).aspx). Of course to support XP you need to implement the template approach too.